# Odoo menu buttons missing on install

Tags: installation, odoo, odoo-8

As the title says, I installed Odoo, but I don't have any available options in the menu.

I tried reinstalling a 2nd time, but I got the same result.

**How does one even troubleshoot this?**

[Odoo 8 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pugqS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not yet installed any of the default modules. Once any module is installed (Sales, Purchases, CRM, etc.), the appropriate tabs will be added to the top menu.

Answer (score 0):

It is default functionality of odoo. you need to give technical access rights to admin user

just check the "Technical Features" in Administrator users form view. then you can see additional technical setting menus